# For-Loops in R - Changing the sequences for monthly returns

Tags: r, for-loop, finance

I have daily stock returns over several years and want to compound monthly stock returns. My data looks the following:

```
R2[1:5, 1:5]
                       1996-01-01 1996-01-02 1996-01-03 1996-01-04 1996-01-05
BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A'          1  0.9813084   0.981746  0.9862571  0.9836066
MORGAN STANLEY                  1  1.0053210   1.007944  0.9894978  0.9867380
GOLDMAN SACHS GP.              NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
CHARLES SCHWAB                  1  1.0248524   1.018196  0.9642593  1.0061998
BLACKROCK                      NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

Dates are columnwise, names of the companies rowwise. The daily returns are numeric.
Therefore for one given month, I apply the following:

```
R4 <- R4 %>% 
      mutate("1996-02" = apply(select(R2, matches("1996-02")), 1, prod))

R4[1:5, 1:2]
                         1996-01   1996-02
BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A' 0.9937695 1.1128527
MORGAN STANLEY         1.1516025 0.9930737
GOLDMAN SACHS GP.             NA        NA
CHARLES SCHWAB         1.2484572 1.0149366
BLACKROCK                     NA        NA
```

I want a loop that automatically calculates the monthly returns from 1996 to 2020 and tried this:

```
R3 <- for(i in 1996:2020) {
  for(j in 1:12) {
    mutate("i-j" = apply(select(R2, matches ("i-j")), 1, prod)) 
    }
  }
```

How would I have to define i and j correctly so that the loop mutates variables for every month over the whole period and adjusts the daily stock returns which have to be used to calculate that monthly return? At the moment I just put them as a placeholder.

Or is there a better and easier way?

**Edit** - To reproduce my data:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA), 
                 c(0.981308411214953, 1.00532100309623, NA, 1.02485242822646, NA), 
                 c(0.981746031746032, 1.0079443588933, NA, 1.01819550348529, NA), 
                 c(0.986257073565077, 0.989497753854871, NA, 0.964259312827436, NA), 
                 c(0.983606557377049, 0.986737970101638, NA, 1.00619979334022, NA))

colnames(df) <- as.Date(c("1996-01-01", "1996-01-02", "1996-01-03", "1996-01-04", "1996-01-05")) 
rownames(df) <- c("BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A'", "MORGAN STANLEY", "GOLDMAN SACHS GP.", "CHARLES SCHWAB", "BLACKROCK")
```

**Solution:**

```
R3 <- R2 %>%
  rownames_to_column("company") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -company) %>%
  mutate(name = as.Date(name), 
         year = year(name),
         month = month(name),
         day = day(name)) %>%
  group_by(company, year, month) %>%
  summarise(value = prod(value, na.rm = FALSE))
```

Comment: Can you provide data in a reproducible format using `dput(R2[1:5, 1:5])` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, sure: structure(list(`1996-01-01` = c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA), `1996-01-02` = c(0.981308411214953, 
1.00532100309623, NA, 1.02485242822646, NA), `1996-01-03` = c(0.981746031746032, 
1.0079443588933, NA, 1.01819550348529, NA), `1996-01-04` = c(0.986257073565077, 
0.989497753854871, NA, 0.964259312827436, NA), `1996-01-05` = c(0.983606557377049, 
0.986737970101638, NA, 1.00619979334022, NA)), row.names = c("BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A'", 
"MORGAN STANLEY", "GOLDMAN SACHS GP.", "CHARLES SCHWAB", "BLACKROCK"
), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I put it in as an edit, @RonakShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you can get the data in long format and calculate product of each year and each company.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  rownames_to_column('company') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -company) %>%
  mutate(name = as.Date(name), 
         year = year(name)) %>%
  group_by(company, year) %>%
  summarise(value = prod(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I just changed it so that it also groups by month to see the monthly returns. Thank you very much!